# Javascript array undefined when creating it with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Further up the page I am creating a filterComparables[] array

```
var filterComparables[<?=$x?>] = <?php echo json_encode($comparables); ?>;
```

At the bottom of the page I have:

```
var propID = parseInt($(this).closest('tr').find('.propID').text());
var property = filterComparables[propID];
```

I've debugged and propID correctly returns the int value, however when trying to access filterComparables[propID], it is returning "filterComparables is not defined at HTMLElement.". I've also tried strictly accessing filterComparables[0] with the same result.

Is it somehow because I am creating the index'd array in PHP up the page and it's not registering in the DOM? I'm confused.

Comment: What does `console.log(JSON.stringify(filterComparables))` log?

Comment: I'm a bit sceptical about how you create the `filterComparables` array. Do you create it in a loop? Then keep in mind, that you overwrite the whole arrray over and over again by `var`. If not, why do you use `<?=$x?>` there? It would be obsolete. And isn't it `'<?php echo json_encode($comparables); ?>';` and then use `JSON.parse` in your code?

Comment: @eisbehr if they put '' around the json, javascript would not parse it into an object automatically.  They would have to JSON.parse it

Comment: Thats what i wrote?! I was not 100% sure if it's valid to put the output of php directly there. Aren't there any cases where json_encode should be parsed again?! Not sure yet. @Taplar

Comment: Array size is not used in JavaScript when declaring an array. Try: `var filterComparables = <?php echo json_encode($comparables); ?>;`

Comment: @eisbehr it's entirely situational, such as an ajax request would be returning a string that would have to be parsed, but in this case the javascript is being generated.  So `var x = {"x":"y"};` works just as well as the string version being parsed, just with one less operation being typed by the programmer.

Comment: The key take away here... is @Scoop, you need to look at your RAW HTML SOURCE and see if the definition you think you are doing, is actually coming out as it should be. The extremely slim detail you have provided us does not shed any light other than you have just one definition, of one value, of one array index. Is it even in a `script` block?

Comment: Can you add the value ( from html source ) of your javascript variable `filterComparables` as it appears?

Answer (score 0):

Creating the indexed array in PHP should be fine, the way that you are declaring the filterComparables variable is likely the issue here, I messed around with it a bit and here's a simplified form of your script that I came up with that works for me:

```
<?php
    $x = 1;
    $comparables = array('foo','bar','bas');
?>

<script>
    var filterComparables = [];
    filterComparables[<?=$x?>] = <?php echo json_encode($comparables); ?>;
</script>
<p>some html for filler</p>
<script>
// var propID = parseInt($(this).closest('tr').find('.propID').text());
var property = filterComparables[1];
console.log(property);
</script>
```

Notice I declared filterComparables and typed it, then started assigning values to it.